# Is it possible to add a JFrame to a JPanel in java?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have been working on a series of JPanel and I wanted to add a JFrame from another class to one of my panels. Can this be done.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A window within a window?

Comment: Agree, this doesn't make much sense without some context. Please give us a little more detail for this question and for your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add any `Window` to another component, doing so results in a `RuntimeException`. What you can do is add the [`contentPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29) from the `JFrame` to your `JPanel`.